# rebasing part of an unrelated branch

Tags: git

I am playing with git-p4 sync. It does not work if I sync with ranges. As a result, i got an idea:  sync into a separate branch and try to rebase it on the previously synced branch.

As a result, both branches are unrelated and the first commit of the second branch has the same contents as the top of the first branch;

```
                  ==
prev sync: |A1 A2 A3|
new sync:        |B1 B2 B3|
                  ==
                  B1 == A3
```

what i want to get at the end is

```
|A1 A2 A3 B2' B3'|
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a [`rebase --onto`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

```
git checkout prev-sync
git rebase --onto pre-sync B1 new-sync
```

That should replay any commit *after* `B1` up to `new-sync` HEAD onto `prev-sync`.

The [OP Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143850/serge)  adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999579/rebasing-part-of-an-unrelated-branch/57000258#comment100549648_57000258):

> Somehow it created unexpected conflicts in creation of files.
>
> So did a simple `cherry-pick` with options `--keep-empty --strategy-option=theirs`, needed to fully automate the process.
> I also was able to do it with `git cherry-pick B1..new-sync` with the same extra qualifiers.

Comment: thanks. Somehow it created unexpected conflicts in creation of files. So did a simple cherry-pick. `--keep-empty --strategy-option=theirs ` quals were needed to fully automate the process. I also was able to do it with `git cherry-pick B1..new-sync` with the same extra qualifiers.

Comment: @Serge Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.